# iOS Cloud Providers

Tags: ios, icloud, dropbox

I've noticed that 3rd party cloud providers are not what I consider to be first-class citizens.  For example, I can't specify a Dropbox folder as the Safari download folder.  Nor can I link a folder from Dropbox into one of the text editor apps (

Both of these I can do with iCloud Drive.   Is this because Dropbox doesn't implement APIs or Apple does allow this functionality with 3rd party cloud providers.

Thanks, just curious.

Comment: I would guess that this is an Apple thing since you can't even change the folder location within iClouds itself.

Comment: Interestingly enough I can select Working Copy (git client) as a location for the downloads.